# Could not launch debug, the App Engine project was not found

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I used the App Engine connected Android wizard to create a linked GAE and Android project in Eclipse.  I've done a reinstall of Eclipse and managed to break the link between the AppEngine and Android projects such that when I try to debug the Android project as a 'Llocal App Engine connected Android Application' I get the message 'Could not launch debug, the App Engine project was not found'.

As my installation no longer has the wizard for creating the App Engine/Android connected project (thanks Google), I can't start again.  So my question is How do I recreate the link?

Thanks Tim